# How to find EOL's(end of line) in Jquery selectize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have a requirement, in which, when a user pastes a list of values from excel into [jquery selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/), it should recognize each line as a value instead of identifing the entire list as one value.

say for example, when I paste the below list containing 2 values, selectize should identify 'bill gates' as one value and 'steve jobs' as another,but
by default, it identifies the entire list as one value('bill gates steve jobs').

List:

```
bill gates
steve jobs
```

I have shared a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/08z7vexn/1/) for your reference, let me know if there is a way to implement it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit your excel files to include ',' after each enter. Be it at new line or same line, it should add the values in a separate tag.

Try pasting:

bill gates,
steve jobs

bill gates,steve jobs

In your jsfiddle and it should work.

Comment: In that case, you want to loop through the excel -> obj (rows) and then add item and then refresh selectize. 

Checkout the doc: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: the problem is, I am not able to identify EOL's (rows) inorder to loop through them because when a list is pasted into selectize , it will automatically delimit each row with spaces, which is also available in each value in the list.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue-- I cached all the pasted text and then modified it, before programmatically pasting it on the Selectize control. You can find the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4zfw6p96/) here.

HTML code:

```
<div class="demo">              
       <div class="control-group">
            <label for="input-tags">Tags:</label>
            <input type="text" id="input-tags" class="demo-default" value="awesome,neat">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var pastedText = undefined;
['paste'].forEach(function (event) {
    document.addEventListener(event, function (e) {
        var str = undefined;        
        if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData("Text"))
            str = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
        else
            if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData('text'))
                str = e.clipboardData.getData('text');        
        pastedText = str;        
    });
});

var onItemAddEventHandler = function (value, $item) {       
    var tempStr = undefined;
    if (pastedText !== undefined) {
        // Replace all newline chars to | (pipe).
        tempStr = pastedText.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '|');
        tempStr = tempStr.replace(/,/g, '|');       
        if (tempStr.length>0)
          this.$control_input.val(tempStr);        
        pastedText = undefined;                    
        this.removeOption(value);
        $item.remove();        
        return;
    }
    if (value.indexOf("|") === -1)
        return;    
    var tempItem = value;
    value = value.replace(/,/g, '|');
    value = value.split("|");
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        if(value[i].trim()!="")
        this.createItem(value[i].trim());
    }
    this.removeOption(tempItem);
    $item.remove();
    return;    
}


$('#input-tags').selectize({
                    persist: false,
                    createOnBlur: true,
                    create: true,
          onItemAdd: function (value, $item) {
          onItemAddEventHandler.call(this, value, $item); 
          }          
});
```